# Size and order changes after converting pandas dataframe to xarray dataset

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to export a dataframe to a netcdf file. As far as I know I can do this with the xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf function. Therefore I have to convert my dataframe to an xarray dataset. Here is what I am doing:

```
ypredicted_df = pd.DataFrame(ypredicted, index=ytest.index, columns=ytest.columns.values)
ypredicted_ds = ypredicted_df.to_xarray()  # to ds
ypredicted_ds.to_netcdf(os.path.join(output_path, 'ypredicted_wholescene_highres_' + str(max_features) + '.nc'))
```

ypredicted is a ndarray.
When I am printing ypredicted_df and ypredicted_ds.to_dataframe() to check if something changed, I see, that part of the order and the size changed:

```
print(ypredicted_df)

                       ST_B10
lat       lon
50.684918 13.282882 -0.213598
          13.283247  0.521064
          13.283613  0.162646
          13.283978  0.090892
          13.284343 -0.060037
...                       ...
51.397346 13.671611  4.871557
          13.671977  4.168761
          13.672342  1.421363
          13.672708  1.761741
          13.673073  2.938208

[5979909 rows x 1 columns]



print(ypredicted_ds.to_dataframe())

                       ST_B10
lat       lon
50.684918 13.282882 -0.213598
          13.283247  0.521064
          13.283613  0.162646
          13.283978  0.090892
          13.284343 -0.060037
...                       ...
51.397346 12.281465  3.387909
          12.281099  3.021199
          12.280734  2.889664
          12.280369  3.197318
          12.280003  2.702418

[7441114 rows x 1 columns]
```

1. The size of the dataframe is not equal
2. the order of the last rows are different (descending, while the first rows are ascending)

I already checked if some nans were included, but when I drop nans, the size does not change.

Can somebody explain, what is happening here? Why are the dataframes different after converting from pandas dataframe to xarray dataset? Is there another way to do so, so the dataframe stays the same? Or can I export the dataframe to netcdf directly?

Thank you for your help :)

**UPDATE**:

I tried again to drop nans and now the size is the same, but still the order is wrong. I do not now if that has some effect when I am plotting it.

```
print(ypredicted.to_dataframe().dropna(how='any'))

                       ST_B10
lat       lon
50.684918 13.282882 -0.213598
          13.283247  0.521064
          13.283613  0.162646
          13.283978  0.090892
          13.284343 -0.060037
...                       ...
51.397346 12.281465  3.387909
          12.281099  3.021199
          12.280734  2.889664
          12.280369  3.197318
          12.280003  2.702418

[5979909 rows x 1 columns]
```

But still, for plotting I need a dataset, because I have not found a way to plot a dataframe. Therefore I still need to drop the nan from the dataset. I found *[xarray.Dataset.dropna](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.dropna.html)*, but it does not work yet:

The first thing I tried was:

```
ypredicted_ds.dropna(how='any')
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_randomforest_dem.py", line 174, in <module>
    output_path_identifier, 3)
  File "/lustre/scratch2/ws/1/stwa779b-master/04_workspace/randomforest/randomforest.py", line 104, in randomforest
    print(dif_ds.dropna(how='any'))
TypeError: dropna() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dim'
```

Then I tried:

```
ypredicted_ds.dropna('lon', how='any').to_dataframe()
```

error message:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ST_B10]
Index: []
(5979909, 1)
```

```
ypredicted_ds.dropna('lat', how='any').to_dataframe()
```

error message:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ST_B10]
Index: []
(5979909, 1)
```

None of them is working. When dropping nan via lon and lat, I can imagine that in every lon or lat at least one nan appears and therefore the dataset is empty. Does anybody now how use xarrays *ds.dropna()*?

**How do I plot?**
As an addition to see, how I am trying to plot the dataset:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))
ax.imshow(ypredicted_ds['ST_B10'], cmap=cmap)
```

Comment: Just to make sure: Have you `.dropna()`-ed after `ypredicted_ds.to_dataframe()`? `.to_dataframe` [does](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_dataframe.html?highlight=to_dataframe) : _The DataFrame is indexed by the **Cartesian product** of this dataset’s indices._ And this can significantly inflate the dataframe (I've been there).

Comment: Hey Timus, that is strange, I really used dropna() before and it did not work. But now it does. I used `ypredicted_ds.to_dataframe().dropna(how='any')`. Now the size of the dataframe is the same  Still I need a dataset to use my _imshow_ for plotting and therefore I tried to drop the nans in the dataset (`ypredicted_ds.dropna(how='any')`), but I can not figure out how to use the parameter _dim_. I will add what I tried to my post and also the plotting function :)